# How to convert a type []os.FileInfo into a string?

Tags: go

I'm using this code to dynamically extract template filenames from a directory using this code:

```
files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("./views")
    htmlFiles := ".html"
    for _, f := range files {
        if strings.Contains(files, htmlFiles) {
            fmt.Println(f.Name())
        }
    }
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
cannot use files (type []os.FileInfo) as type string in argument to strings.Contains
```

So, how to convert `type []os.FileInfo` into a `string` (or how do to this in a simpler way)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value returned by `ioutil.ReadDir` is a `[]os.FileInfo`, which is a slice of interfaces. There's no general way to convert that into a meaningful string. You want to compare the name for each file individually:

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("./views")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, f := range files {
    if strings.HasSuffix(f.Name(), ".html") {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
    }
}
```